# Structure left after deletion

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a very basic arrow, and I've cut it from a cube, only to find that this persists after deleting the cube. I am not entirely sure what to call it, hence searching for help has been pretty hard, but if anyone could answer, it would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The dashed cube is drawn because you've enabled the texture space option. This can happen accidentally by a shortcut.

[image]